# Java FX-8: Why is EventType generic?

Tags: java, events, generics, javafx-8

The system of EventType is highly confusing in JavaFX.
I think the reason for this is that the designers decided to make
the EventType class itself generic.

Is there any practical use for this or is this just some
obscure form of ensuring type safety ?

I would imagine classes would be made generic only if the generic type is returned somewhere to a calling class. Otherwise what's the point ?

Comment: So that you don't have to cast an [`Event`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html) subclass each time you want to access its methods.

Comment: I also assume this works great for [lamba expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). See [Mary had a little λ - Using Java 8 Lambda Expressions for Event Handling](http://learnjavafx.typepad.com/weblog/lambda-expressions/): *"When a lambda expression has a single parameter and its type is inferred, the parentheses are not required"*.

Comment: My question is why is the class EventType generic. The article refers to why EventHandlers are generic which I completely understand. But why is EventType ??

Comment: Think of the EventType as a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), it needs to know and enforce what types of Events it is dealing with.

Comment: Collection is generic to type <T> because it returns T in some of its methods to the calling class. EventHandler is generic to type<E> because in the handle method - which is overridden in the calling class - it enables the program to get the specific event type. In other words both cases the calling program is avoided having to cast. These are the only two uses for generics I can imagine. But as far as I see neither of these apply to EventType. So why is it generic?

Comment: Those aren't the only uses for generic classes: another use is as a runtime-type token (such as `Class<T>`), which is what is happening here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are `Event` classes, i.e. subclasses of `Event`, that define particular methods for that class. E.g. `MouseEvent` defines various methods that can be used to query the coordinates of the mouse when the event occurred (`getX()`, `getY()`, `getSceneX()`, `getScreenX()` etc); `ScrollEvent` defines methods to query the amount and direction of the scroll: `getDeltaX()`, `getDeltaY()`, etc).

`EventType` is a more fine-grained object that specifies what happened. So constants of the `EventType` class include `MOUSE_CLICKED`, `MOUSE_PRESSED`, `KEY_TYPED`, `SCROLL_STARTED`, etc. Each of these values is associated with a particular `Event` subclass.

The event registration method is `addEventHandler(...)`. This method takes two parameters: an `EventType` (which type of event to listen for), and an `EventHandler`. The `EventHandler` is generic for obvious reasons: by defining an `EventHandler<T extends Event>` you get to define a `handle(T event)` method that takes the appropriate event object, which you can then query in the type-specific way. (E.g. an `EventHandler<MouseEvent>` has a `handle(MouseEvent event)` method, which can query the coordinates of the mouse, etc).

Now, it clearly only makes sense to register an `EventHandler<T>` for an `EventType` that is associated with the `Event` subclass `T`. Furthermore, it's desirable to allow for the compiler to enforce this. By making the `EventType` class generic: `EventType<T extends Event>`, we get to let the compiler enforce this rule. `MOUSE_CLICKED` is not just an instance of `EventType`, it's an instance of `EventType<MouseEvent>`. Since the signature of the `addEventHandler(...)` method is `addEventHandler(EventType<T>, EventHandler<T>)`, the compiler enforces that the handler is "for the same class of event" as the event type.

When you combine this with using lambdas (or I suppose with type inference, in particular), it becomes quite powerful:

```
node.addEventHandler(MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {...});
```

Because `MOUSE_CLICKED` is specifically an `EventType<MouseEvent>`, the compiler is able to infer that the event handler defined by the lambda is an `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`, and thus that `e` is a `MouseEvent`. So the compiler can now infer that

```
node.addEventHandler(MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> System.out.println(e.getX()));
node.addEventHandler(KEY_TYPED, e -> System.out.println(e.getText()));
```

are legal, but

```
node.addEventHandler(MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> System.out.println(e.getText()));
```

is not. If `EventType` were not generic, this would not be possible.

(The same is true without lambdas, but the less concise syntax doesn't drive the point home as well. But without `EventType` being generic, there would be no way for the compiler to reject

```
node.addEventHandler(MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) { }
});
```

Again, the fact the `MOUSE_CLICKED` has type `EventType<MouseEvent>` means this will not compile.)

Technically, `EventType` is used as a "Runtime-type token". It's being used not just to say which events we are interested in, but also which type of event handler should be used to handle the event. Other examples of this use of generics include `Class<T>`: see [this part of the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) for a brief discussion.

Comment: Awsome explanation. Thanks. though I don't see the parallel with the runtime-type token. Here the use seems to be specifically for compile time and not runtime? It seems that EventType was made generic specifically so that in the method addEventHandler(EventType<T>,EventHandler<T>), the compiler could infer the type parameter if a lambda is used. If EventType were not generic, we would either have to use the old form: new EventHandler<type specified> or if we used a lambda it would default to Event as the type. Having this feature allows us to use a lambda with the specific type supplied ?

Comment: As I understand it, "runtime-type token" refers to a token that represents the runtime type of another entity. That may not be a standard (or accurate) interpretation. So here the `EventType` object is a token that represents the runtime type of the event handler.

Comment: It doesn't only apply to using lambdas, the same is true when you use any `EventHandler` implementation. It's just that the enhanced type-inference that accompanies lambda expressions makes it more obviously useful. See the update to the answer.